# Add custom script to fish shell config

Tags: ubuntu, fish

I would like add script to **fish** shell config, like default bash on Ubuntu :

```
## Auto load nvm when there's a .nvmrc file
OLD_PWD=""
promptCommand() {
    if [ "$OLD_PWD" != "$PWD" ] ;
        then
        OLD_PWD="$PWD"
        if [ -e .nvmrc ] ;
            then nvm use;
        fi
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=promptCommand
```

But i don't find the file config for **fish** shell.

Anyone have already add custom script in **fish** ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following link
[Frequently Asked Questions](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html)

> **How do I run a command every login? What's fish's equivalent to .bashrc?**
>
> Edit the file ~/.config/fish/config.fish, creating it if it does not exist (Note the leading period).